# Getting a 304 response from newly created github page

Tags: github-pages

I created a github page with jeyll as per https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/getting-started-with-github-pages

This is my public repo https://github.com/MrBuggySan/mrbuggysan.github.io & this is the github page link https://mrbuggysan.github.io/

I've setup the github-pages dependency on the gemfile and this same repo works for me locally. Is there something I missed here?

Comment: It works for me. What is the problem? The `index.md` is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have configured the main branch, folder docs, as [publishing shource](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

Second, in that docs folder, you should see what Jekyll has generated: `docs` the "destination" folder in [Jekyll configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/).
(like Jekyll itself does when [it builds its documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/actions/runs/358395683/workflow#L42))